# How to change the "Bundle Identifier" within React Native?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Starting a new react-native project, the xcode-project gots the bundle-identifier "org.reactjs.native.example.XYZApp". XYZ is the placeholder here for my real project name.

Is there any way to change this bundle identifier on react-native side? Sure, I can change it in XCode. But this is not safe because it can be overriden when react-native will recreate the xcode-project, which could happen at any time, as well es when rebuilding the project.

Answer (score 58):

Based on the react-native version you are using there are bunch of files that have to be changed on both platforms (android and ios)

### List of files to edit:

### IOS

1. *[application_build_scheem]*.plist (this is a dict/xml file that contains keys that are used by default **if no changes** added to project (react-native-cli init type of project)

### ANDROID

1. strings.xml (change *app_name* key value)
2. manifest.xml (change *package* attribute)
3. build.gradle (change *applicationId* value)
4. MainActivity.java (change java class *package*)
5. MainApplication.java (change java class *package*)

It's worth mentioning that there is an an npm module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ci-tools) that does all of the above; use it and make life easy.

### Update (6/Mar/2019)

**Update Folder Paths:**

We also need to change the folder paths to match new name -- change `com.oldName` to `com.newname.mobile`, then change folder paths from `app/src/java/com/oldName/` to `app/src/java/com/newname/mobile/`.

Answer (score 13):

For those who want a simple way to do exactly this I create react-native-app-id, It'll basically edit the files mentioned. react-native-ci-tools actually forked my code to produce a now outdated react-native-app-id-fixed , which won't work with the latest react native. Mine however will..

https://github.com/kyle-ssg/react-native-app-id

usage is as easy as `react-native-app-id com.foo.bar`

**Edit** : Deprecated in favour of https://github.com/junedomingo/react-native-rename

Comment: What if I want Android package name as a **com.foo.bar.android** and IOS bundle id as **com.foo.bar.ios**?

Comment: Well submitting a PR for that would be super simple, would just need to check for some args around the single call for process ios / android. Could be called like react-native-app-id com.foo.bar --ignore-ios

Answer (score 10):

**To update iOS bundle id -**

- From terminal or command prompt navigate to react-native project folder and then go inside iOS folder.
- enter command **Open ProjectName.xcodeproj**

This command will open the project in Xcode where you need to update bundle identifier information of the app

**To update android package name follow below steps -**

- Update folder structure inside “android/app/src/main/java/” folder
  based on your new package name e.g "com/companyName/appName"
- Update package name inside MainActivity.java file
- Update package name inside MainApplication.java file
- Update package name inside /android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
  file
- Update package name inside /android/app/BUCK file
- Update package name inside /android/app/build.gradle file

Answer (score 6):

Here's my solution without adding some external packages.
Just run  `npx react-native-rename <newName> -b <bundleIdentifier>` inside your project root directory.
https://github.com/junedomingo/react-native-rename

Comment: This works. However, It doesn't change the package name in "google-services.json" file, so you have to do it manually.

Comment: Of course, it can't go over google-services.json or GoogleService-info.plist, but since you've changed your bundleIdentifier you'll need to change it manually in your firebase/google console anyways and the console will regenerate these files with new bundleIdentifier for you.

Answer (score 2):

Edit the `PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER` associated with the project in `ios/project.pbxproj`. **It is much safer to use XCode.**

I know that the question asked to do it without XCode, for people keen on **using Xcode**, when inside your react native project:

1. `xed ios` Open the ios folder in xcode
2. Click the top left icon (`project navigator`)
3. Click the root item in the left panel `ProjectName`
4. In the center view, click `General`
5. Under `identity`, change the Bundle identifier

Answer (score 1):

I have a more lowkey solution that I have been using. This is not a replacement for the above solutions, but simply, one more way to do it. I have only tested this on iOS but I assume it would work for Android as well.

I noticed that in most cases, the project created would have a com.xyz.something which is something like this.

```
org.reactjs.native.example.abcyourprojectname-extras
```

I realised, instead of checking each and every folder (and not having to use Xcode), I simply do a search for (in Visual Studio Code, with the project folder open)

```
org.reactjs.native.example
```

This would list all the files with the bundle identifier. Just change it your preferred bundle identifier, and thats about it. This way, even if tomorrow, there are any file changes or format changes or whatever, searching will still be consistent way of doing things.

(again, this is a low key solution, but it seems to work for me)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change bundle identifier in react-native project. You must have to change app identifier separately for both side android and ios.

**ios**

> Select root project in xcode, select General tab, You can see Bundle
>   identifier into identity section and change your new bundle identifier
>   for ios application

**android**

> 1. Goto your AndroidManifest.xml.
> 2. Just place your cursor in the package name, don't select it just place it.
> 3. Then press shift+F6(window)/F6 (mac) you will get a popup window, fill new identifier and select Rename package. It will change
>      from everywhere in android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Even with react-native-app-id you must move the files to the new folder

I ended using a npm task for upgrading, first upgrade then run the command for rename, move the android files to the correct path and re-link just in case

Comment: question was related to iOS build. If you think your answer is better compared to previous answers then please provide extra details (like commands to execute , etc.)

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately not. In fact we were just discussing this today in the react Native Facebook group.
https://m.facebook.com/groups/586400221495560?view=permalink&id=738954276240153&comment_id=739065029562411&notif_t=group_comment_reply&ref=m_notif

The best plan right now is to choose the 'd' option when upgrading to verify the files before allowing then to be overridden.

Comment: Is it still the case that we are not able to specify the ios bundle id anywhere in the React project?