# App won't run after changed bundle identifier

Tags: xcode, react-native

my app was working normally. After I have changed app's bundle identifier through Xcode it started to throwing error when i write `npx react-native run-ios`. I tried change it back to old bundle identifier like; `org.reactjs.native.example.appname`. And it started working normally again. I want to change it to something like that; `org.appname`.

I tried upvoted solutions on this post; [How to change the “Bundle Identifier” within React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36119754/how-to-change-the-bundle-identifier-within-react-native)
but it wont work for me.

Thank you for reading, i will be glad if  you could help me. Have a nice day.

Comment: What error did you get? Was it something about bundle identifiers not matching? If you ran the app on a device with the old bundle ID, then changed it and tried to run it again iOS will think something bad is happening. You can delete the original copy of the app from the device and then the new bundle ID should work fine.

Comment: Also, your bundle ID should be at least three things long, not two. `org.cemk.appname` or something would be good, but `org.appname` is too short.

Comment: i will try both of them and try to be more specific about error when i able to access to mac. Thanks

Comment: did it resolved for you?